# why tkinter won't import, even if the package is installed?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am getting an error when doing the Tkinter import; it says that _tkinter fail, because TK is not configured.

Now; I am not sure why is that; considering that I did yum install tkinter, and the package was installed.

I have Python 2.7.3, running on linux; the package installed is tkinter-2.6.6-51.el6.x86_64. Why is it not importing?

Comment: have you installed python-tkinter (might be python-tk)?
do you import upper or lowercase ("tkinter" would be for python3.x, "Tkinter" for python2.x)

Comment: I was not able to find any python-tkinter; the package available is called simply tkinter I believe. I did try to use both with capital and without capital but it didn't make any difference. I suspect I just have an incorrect install; will just wipe out everything and start all over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783810/install-tkinter-for-python).

As you are running on linux this should work.

If you are not using `apt-get`: this should also work using `yum` or `pacman`.

Please note that tkinter itself is not the python libraries but the Framework based on Tcl/Tk.

Comment: Good point; I did the manual install; following one of the reply to the thread that you mentioned, and now it works. Probably it doesn't like when you don't build from scratch everything. Working now. Thanks!