# Linux Mint 17 tkinter not installed

Tags: python, linux, tkinter, linux-mint, python-3.5

I was trying to run a program that I have been making and ran into a problem with tkinter not being installed, as when I try to run my script in pycharm I get this error: `ImportError: No module named '_tkinter', please`install the python3-tk package`

So I searched on here and found a solution and entered these commands:

```
sudo apt-get install python-support
sudo update-python-modules -a
```

which didn't work so I tried:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-tk
```

which was tagged as the answer on this question but it threw this error at me:

```
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

Being pretty new to linux and the terminal, I am completely clueless as to how to do this.

I am using python 3.5 and just want to install tkinter so I can run this script, also before anyone asks yes I have imported `tkinter` and not `Tkinter`.

Comment: show your import statement

Comment: you checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783810/install-tkinter-for-python?

Comment: I checked out the answer for that and still get the same error

Comment: My import statement: `from tkinter import *`

Comment: Have you ran the `sudo dpkg` statement it tells you? You just run that from the same place you are doing `sudo apt-get` stuff.

Comment: I get this: `dpkg: error: dpkg status database is locked by another process`

Comment: Now if I try to run `sudo apt-get install python3-tk` I get this error: `E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?`

Comment: If you run `ps aux | grep apt` is there any output?

Comment: You are running another instance of `apt`, which locks `/var/lib/dpkg/lock`.

Comment: @wilbur if I run that command you gave me I got this output: http://pastebin.com/K7dHAcWC

Comment: @pydev I don't understand, i've used apt before to install software so why doesn't it work now.

Answer (score 2):

`sudo apt-get install python3-tk` is the correct way to install tkinter for Python 3 on Linux. However, you interrupted apt while it was installing. To fix the errors, run the command the error message suggested and then install tkinter.

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install python3-tk
```

Then you can add `from tkinter import *`, `import tkinter as tk` or `import tkinter` to the beginning of your program depending on how you want to use it. You may also be interested in installing idle-python3.4.

Next time you need to install something just open the software manager from Menu, search for the program and install it :-)

Answer (score -2):

Well when all logic fails- panic. Look for the illogical. I found that I was not running Python 3. My text editor is **Geany**, and reverts everything to run its default, which was set at Python 2. That included #!.

So, change the defaults in Geany:

*Build > Set build commands >*  then in the dialogs replace every instance of Python with **Python3**