# macOS, Tkinter, Python (Macports) gives error "no $DISPLAY environment variable"

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, tcl

I'm getting a "no $DISPLAY environment variable" with Python on macOS. That's MacPorts python 3.7, not the native python. I want to use MacPorts python with virtual environments so I can keep my projects clean. I also have to use MacPorts not Homebrew.

I've unsuccessfully tried setting the $DISPLAY value to :0.0 and the following link doesn't help because I'm not using matplotlib and I'm running on a machine with a display [Issue with tkinter, python and seaborn: _tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41951310/issue-with-tkinter-python-and-seaborn-tkinter-tclerror-no-display-name-and-n?noredirect=1#comment71095010_41951310)

I understand from here [https://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/#built-in-8-6-8] that using X11 is no longer the recommended path, rather using Aqua Cocoa Tk is.

The question: What's the trick to getting this environment variable set correctly?

My stack is:

macOS Mojave

Macports with the following relevant ports installed:

- py37-tkinter @3.7.4 python/py-tkinter
- py37-virtualenv @16.7.2 python/py-virtualenv
- python37 @3.7.4 lang/python37
- tcl @8.6.9 lang/tcl
- tk @8.6.9 x11/tk
- virtualenv_select @0.1 python/virtualenv_select

when I run

```
import tkinter as tk
tk._test()
```

I get

```
_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, down to the wire. Could not get `tkinter` to behave properly with any sort of graphical interfaces, wanted to be consistent in using MacPorts for my Python files, and I am not currently using `matplotlib` for anything.

Running macOS 10.15.5, I found that the problem seemed to be that my `tk` port and my `xorg-server` ports weren't communicating with one another politely. I had installed the former as a dependency; as a result, the former installation defaulted to the `x11` variant (as is the case with OP's port).

I'm not sure about  how to make the Aqua Cocoa version work, but reinstalling `tk` and specifying the `quartz` variant solved the problem for me:

```
sudo port install tk +quartz
```

If this works for you, your call to to `tk._test()` ought to stop returning your given `TclError`.

Hopefully.

Comment: Tk can be built on macOS in both X11 and Aqua (native) modes. Both are supported.

Answer (score 1):

Fairly recent versions of macOS don't have an Xserver by default, so you'll need to install one as well. [XQuartz](https://www.xquartz.org/) works enough as far as I'm aware (i.e., I'm using it).

The other option is to use a build of Tk that's using the Aqua back end instead of the X11 back end.

Comment: ActiveState TCL should be that right? I installed it but Python is still giving me the same error. Do I need to rebuild Python or is there an easier way to point it at ActiveState?