# python savefig shows error message : "TypeError: compile() expected string without null bytes"

Tags: python, matplotlib, fig

So I am having an issue when I try to save figures in Python. 
If I create a figure f, and try to save it using the line

`f.savefig('Test.eps', format='eps')`

It yields  yields the following error message :

```
TypeError: compile() expected string without null bytes.
```

It doesn't depend on the figure I want to save or on the format I choose, the error remains.
An example of a code I use could be :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
A=np.array([1,2,3,4])
f=plt.figure(figsize=(13,11))
plt.plot(A)
f.savefig('Test.eps', format='eps')
```

which will yield :

```
TypeError: compile() expected string without null bytes.
```

Anyone knows where this might come from ?

Thanks

Comment: Is there a traceback associated with it? If so, please edit it into your question. `compile` is used for runtime dynamically generated code (usually followed by `eval`-ing it); the traceback would help determine what `matplotlib` magic was doing this.

Comment: This works for me.

Comment: There's no traceback whatsoever appearing. 
Also it worked earlier today so I'm confused. 
I restarted Python and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: There should always be a traceback. Are you running the script from the terminal, or from within some other environment?

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and I had an error but I solved it by installing [python-tk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783810/install-tkinter-for-python). After that, I execute correctly.
Are you sure you installed the packages correctly?.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I disagree. If this solves the problem, it's a perfectly fine answer.

Comment: I think that deleted my last comment. When I published my "answer" I had a reputation less than 50, but I wanted to share what I did.