# Python 2.7 can't find module Tkinter with the capital T

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I am trying to run some plotting libraries that use Tkinter. I am using Python 2.7, and am getting the exact error (capitalization important :))

```
ImportError: No module named Tkinter
```

Seems like a lot of people are running into a similar issue that is solved by making sure to use the capitalized Tkinter versus all lowercase tkinter. I do not believe this is my problem since it is in fact capitalized.

When I run:

```
python --version
```

I get:

```
Python 2.7.5
```

Is there a place I can check to make sure Tkinter is properly installed? Has anyone else seen this particular issue with Python 2.7?

Comment: Are you using windows, as Tkinter only comes per standard with the python files for windows. If using linux, then `apt install python-tk` will install it.

Answer (score -1):

First, run `pip freeze` from the directory you want to use it. If you use a virtual environment, make sure that's active. This will show you all packages currently installed

The more exact option is to check the site-packages where they get installed (I use ipython):

[How do I find the location of my Python site-packages directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122327/how-do-i-find-the-location-of-my-python-site-packages-directory)

```
$ ipython

In [1]: import site

In [2]: site.getsitepackages()
Out[2]: 
['/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages',
 '/Library/Python/3.6/site-packages']
```

then go there:

```
cchilders:/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages 
$ ls
IPython                 jupyter_client              python_dateutil-2.6.0.dist-info
Jinja2-2.9.6.dist-info          jupyter_client-5.0.1.dist-info      pytz
MarkupSafe-1.0.dist-info        jupyter_console             pytz-2017.2.dist-info
Pygments-2.2.0.dist-info        jupyter_console-5.1.0.dist-info     pyzmq-16.0.2.dist-info
__pycache__             jupyter_core                qtconsole
appnope                 jupyter_core-4.3.0.dist-info        qtconsole-4.3.0.dist-info
...etc...
```

The same things you saw on `pip freeze` should show up here.

Make sure you have the package for the right version of python. If using python 3, you have to say:

`pip3 freeze`

But apparently the safest way to install is using `apt` if you have linux:

```
sudo apt-get install python-tk
```

[Install tkinter for Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783810/install-tkinter-for-python)

Comment: Almost all of this is wrong, because Tkinter - being **part of the standard library** - should not ever be expected to be found in the `site-packages` directory. It **cannot be installed using Pip**, and checking for its presence is not Pip's responsibility.