# install Tkinter without accessing root

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I don't have access to root of  my centos7 and I want to install Tkinter from source and I followed the attached link after I downloaded Tcl and tk8  but I faced this problem after I wrote
"make" for the second step

```
In file included from /home/rebali/Downloads/tk8.7a1/unix/../generic/tkPort.h:21:0,
from /home/rebali/Downloads/tk8.7a1/unix/../generic/tkInt.h:19,
from /home/rebali/Downloads/tk8.7a1/unix/../generic/tkStubLib.c:14:
/home/rebali/Downloads/tk8.7a1/unix/../generic/tk.h:96:25: fatal error: X11/Xlib.h: No such file or directory
# include <X11/Xlib.h>
^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [tkStubLib.o] Error 1


frist step
 cd/Downloads/tcl8.7a1/unix
./configure --prefix=/home/rebali/cnel711 --exec-prefix=/home/rebali/cnel711
make 
make install

second step
  cd/Downloads/tk8.7a1/unix

./configure --prefix=/home/rebali/cnel711 --exec-prefix=/home/rebali/cnel711 --with-tcl=/home/rebali/cnel711/lib
make 
make install
```

[Install tkinter for Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783810/install-tkinter-for-python)

Comment: The error message is pretty clear: you need the `X11/Xlib.h` file. I'd guess you need to install the `libx11-dev` package (it would be on Debian; I dunno about redhat).

Comment: @Novel that is the point, how libx11 can be installed provided that we do not have root privileges?