# Trying to create a simple GUI in Python 2.7.6, but Tkinter module seems to be not available for my version

Tags: python, python-2.7, shell, user-interface, tkinter

I tried to create a simple GUI in Python which gets input from the user and execute a shell script based on the user input.

Since it has to call a Shell script, I'm trying to create a GUI in the Python 2.7.6, which is the only version available in Linux Env. I tried to use Tkinter, but its saying ImportError: No module named _tkinter

`ImportError: No module named _tkinter`

Any alternatives or suggestions would be helpful!

Comment: Are you trying to import `_tkinter`? Because that's not the name of the module. Try importing `Tkinter` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried using Tkinter as well, but getting same import error..I think Tkinter is not supported in my Python 2.7.6 version, can u suggest any alternative modules which can be used for creating a simple UI..

Comment: Tkinter is native to all python versions. See https://docs.python.org/2/library/tkinter.html

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install python-tk` if you're on a Debian(-derivate). Proberly a dublicate of [Install tkinter for Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783810/install-tkinter-for-python).

Comment: What do you mean by "Linux Env"?

Comment: Its the Linux environment for which we dont have any access to install or upgrade.. But I have python 3.7 in Windows 10, if there's any way to call the shell script in Linux environment from Windows(Via Python script), please let me know.. Thanks for you time..

Comment: If the linux env supports SSH connection, you can try `paramiko` module.

Comment: tkinter is definitely supported in python 2.7.6. It seems like you have a broken installation.

Comment: Oh, Maybe! :( is there any way to check broken installation? I'll try to check how to use `paramiko` module..

Comment: If the Linux env is 64-bit system, check whether `/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload/_tkinter.so` exists.

Comment: Python was installed without tkinter support.

Comment: Next time, show a [complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146) stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

In python 2.7 the module is called Tkinter (capital T). and the most common usecase is:

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.mainloop()
```

If you are looking for a quick interface option that works on Linux (or any other Operating system) Then maybe look at python-Flask [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/).

This framework will allow you to take HTML, CSS, JS and PHP and transfer the data back to python. So you can build your entire GUI as a webpage, import it to flask, then use URLs to get user inputs back into python.

Comment: Still not working :(, as Bryan said maybe it could be a broken one! Thanks for the suggesting the alternative(Flask), will try to create UI using that! :)

Comment: just a Quick FYI, Flask is not a GUI. you create the GUI in HTML and CSS then use JS to send commands back to Flask (its a webserver). You will need a secondary application to actually view the HTML page (a webbrowser) i have one for python but its built using pyGTK so im not sure if it will work for you.

Comment: Other possible GUI frameworks are GTK, Kivy and PyQt. if you are not familiar with HTML or JS try take a look into them first.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info! It really helps!:)