# Getdist plot not showing up in console

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, jupyter

I'm using [`getdist`](https://getdist.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html) to plot some simulation results. 
In `jupyter`  writing just this line

```
g = plots.getSubplotPlotter()
g.triangle_plot([samples, samples2], filled=True)
```

Python will show plots as we can see [here](https://getdist.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plot_gallery.html).

Now if we want to write it in Python shell and run it with `IDLE`, this does not produce any plot.  `plt.show()` does not work here.

How to instruct python or matplotlib to show the plots and save them?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `getdist` sets the backend to `Agg` (in [this line](https://github.com/cmbant/getdist/blob/50631a328ae8a220bbbba6b054c9df77caccd305/getdist/plots.py#L10)), which is a non-interactive backend and hence cannot produce an interactive figure via `plt.show()`.
This is pretty bad style, because the user should select the backend, not the package. You might want to inform the developpers about this design flaw.

Anyways it would be possible to switch the backend **after** importing getdist, via `plt.switch_backend(..)`. As backend you would need to use any interactive backend you have available, e.g. `"Qt5Agg"` or `"TkAgg"`.

```
import numpy as np
from getdist import plots, MCSamples
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.switch_backend("Qt5Agg")

# .. some code ..

g = plots.getSubplotPlotter()
g.triangle_plot([samples, samples2], filled=True)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you but `ImportError: Failed to import any qt binding`

Comment: And when I use `TkAgg`, I get `FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified`

Comment: Are you able to plot matplotlib plots without getdist at all? If you start a new console and do `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt;
print(plt.get_backend())` what does it show for you?

Comment: with so many wonders, Now I tested it and no I cannot. I was using jupyter without any problem and after installing `git-bash` and `gnuparallel` the plotting task has been broken down. I found out now that even plotting a simple line could not be accomplished. Now could you help me  what should I do please?

Comment: Answering your question: `TkAgg`

Comment: Then it looks like your tk install is broken. Maybe you can reinstall tk?

Comment: I reinstalled, `Ipython`, `jupyter`, `matplotlib`, `kernel` and the problem persists. Now I should do ` pip uninstall python-tk`? and then install? Could you tell me how to install it? I am unacquainted with this parts of Python

Comment: [Yes.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783810/install-tkinter-for-python) For python 3 it might be `python3-tk` though. Not sure which system you are using.

Comment: I am on windows 64 bit, python 3.6.3. But the `pip install python3-tk` does not work for me]

Comment: This link was for linux, I installed ACTIVETCL but there is the same problem. should I reinstall the windows?

Comment: No, don't reinstall windows. This is a python problem, so in the limit you can completely reinstall python and all packages if nothing else helps. I'm sorry I cannot be of more help here, I never experienced problems with tk not working correctly.

Comment: thank you, I will do it. But I think it cannot work. Because I install a python 2.7 while I had py3.6and that one had this problem on my system.