# Trying to make a simple menu with tkinter but returns "Display is not capable of DPMS"

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am very noob and I need help please.

Here's my code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('500x500')

def callback() :
    print ("click!")

b = Button(root, text="OK", command=callback)
b.pack()

mainloop()
```

Comment: what's your `mainloop()`? I don't see its definition. Pleas provide a [complete, minimal, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I said I was a noob so I don't know What are you saying

Comment: I only copy this from one blog and I redimesione this

Comment: Your code works fine. Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: @Aemyl: `mainloop()` is a function in the `tkinter` module and was brought into scope via the `from tkinter import *` statement.

Comment: It's possible that the problem is from repl.it (is were I programe)?

Comment: Okey thank you so much

Comment: @martineau shouldn't it be `root.mainloop()`? Or is that equivalent?

Comment: I think it is .

Comment: @Aemyl: `root.mainloop()` would have also worked (since it's also a universal widget method). With or without a widget, it just runs the Tk main loop.

Comment: I'm sure that your problem comes from this online python evviroment site. Just run your code on your computer and you will see it works. Don't do Gui programming on online sites.

Comment: tkinter was create to work with local GUI (Windows/XWindow) and local monitor/display. So when you run it online on server then it tries to use GUI on server and monitor connected to server. But servers don't need GUIs or monitors. And they don't have GUIs and monitors. Besides you could't see monitor connected to server.

Comment: okey I will try this

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox

root = Tk()
root.geometry('200x60')
root.title('Test Application')

def notify():
    tkMessageBox.showwarning('Notification', 'Display is not capable of DPMS!')

b1 = Button(root, text="Run!", command=notify)
b1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: @uri What do you mean it doesn't work? It works perfectly fine on my machine, can you please be more specific, my guess is that you might not have tkMessageBox.

Answer (score 0):

Uri, you should probably run it on your computer instead of on the web. If you are using a chromebook go into settings and enable Linux.

——-Windows-——

Windows Install:

[Click here](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/)

——-Mac-——

Mac Install:

[click here](https://www.python.org/downloads/mac-osx/)

——-Linux-——

Linux Problems:

[click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783810/install-tkinter-for-python)

Linux Install:

[click here](https://www.python.org/downloads/source/)