# Where is Tkapp located?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm working on creating an interface between tkinter and JSON. I need to look through the code of Tkapp to do so because I need to understand its attributes. Failing that, how can I import it?

```
from tkinter import _tkinter
from _tkinter import tkapp
```

Returns an `ImportError`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Install tkinter for Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783810/install-tkinter-for-python)

Answer (score 0):

`_tkinter` is a C-based module. `tkapp` is defined in its source code which you can find [here on GitHub](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/_tkinter.c).