# Python module turtle not importing correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

This is my first time using the turtle module in python but I can't seem to import it?
Here's my code:

```
import turtle

turtle.shape("turtle")
turtle.speed(1)
turtle.forward(100)
turtle.left(90)
turtle.forward(100)
turtle.left(90)
turtle.forward(100)
turtle.left(90)
turtle.forward(100)
turtle.left(90)

turtle.exitonclick()
```

I run this as `$ python3 example.py`
And I get

```
$ python3 example.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "example.py", line 1, in <module>
from turtle import *
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/turtle.py", line 107, in <module>
import tkinter as TK
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkinter'
```

If I run Python2 `python example.py`

```
$ python example.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "example.py", line 1, in <module>
import turtle
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/turtle.py", line 107, in <module>
import Tkinter as TK
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 42, in <module>
raise ImportError, str(msg) + ', please install the python-tk package'
ImportError: No module named _tkinter, please install the python-tk package
```

Comment: Are you on a virtual environment? If so, have you `pip` installed the dependencies for your program?

Comment: I am not sure how to import pip or install it. @JST99

Comment: Ok I installed pip and I forgot to say I was not in any virtual environment (eg. virtual box, docker etc.)

Comment: You're on Linux, is my guess. Try `sudo apt-get install python-tk`

Comment: @Noah Broyles 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example.py", line 1, in <module>
    import turtle
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/turtle.py", line 107, in <module>
    import tkinter as TK
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkinter'

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: Pop!_OS ubuntu based @NoahBroyles

Comment: Try reading this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783810/install-tkinter-for-python

Comment: @NoahBroyles Thanks! It worked! Will you add an answer, so I can checkmark it?

Comment: @Gosejok Since that was another SO post I can't exactly call that my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was

```
sudo apt install python3-tkinter
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a simple one to solve:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-tk
```

One of the other commenters suggested python-tk which wouldn't work for you here.