# No module named 'tkinter' - error coming up

Tags: python, visual-studio, tkinter

I've been trying to run a certain turtle code in my visual studio 2019 community edition.

but I've been getting this error again and again.
P.S. Normal python is working all fine on the VS ide.

**error**

```
  Message=No module named 'tkinter'

  Source=D:\visual studio\python trials\day6trial\example\example\example.py
  StackTrace:

  File "D:\visual studio\python trials\day6trial\example\example\example.py", line 1, in <module>
    
from turtle import *
```

**the code I've been trying to run is :**

```
from turtle import *


speed(0)

bgcolor('black')

x = 1

while x < 400:

     colormode(255) # this is something that is irrelevant at this point
                # check the pythondocs link at the end for more info


     pencolor(255,255,255) # changes the color of the pen to the rgb coordinates
                     # obtained by the variables r, g, b changing each time

     fd(50 + x)
     rt(90.911)


     x = x+1 

exitonclick()
```

This problem has been occuring since , I installed nodejs and vscode in my laptop.

please help out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python module turtle not importing correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61502272/python-module-turtle-not-importing-correctly)

Comment: no as i am a windows user.