# UserWarning: Matplotlib is currently using agg, so cannot show the figure

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, tkinter

I'm trying to run a basic `matplotlib` example from the [official website](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/cohere.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-cohere-py):

However, when i run the code, my Python interpreter complains and outputs the following message:

```
UserWarning: Matplotlib is currently using agg, which is a non-GUI backend, so cannot show the figure.
plt.show()
```

I've installed `matplotlib` via `pip3 install matplotlib`.
My current `python3` version is 3.9.1 and my OS is Ubuntu 20.04.

I've already tried installing tkinter, as already described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783810/install-tkinter-for-python), with no success.
What should I do? Why is this happening?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please try these, if any works for you:

1. if you are using Jupyter Notebook

   ```
    %matplotlib inline
   ```
2. make sure you have tkinter, recompile python interpreter after installing tkinter
3. try:

   ```
    import matplotlib
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    plt.style.use('ggplot')
    matplotlib.use( 'tkagg' )
    x = [1, 5, 1.5, 4]
    y = [9, 1.8, 8, 11]
    plt.scatter(x,y)
    plt.show()
   ```

Comment: how can i recompile python interpreter?
I'm not using jupyter notebook
even after adding these suggested lines I'm still getting
`import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'`

Comment: I'm not
This is the error that it gives.
I'm running the `matplotlib` example exactly the same as described in the website