Installing Tkinter somehow installs a different module
I'm on Linux Ubuntu 22.10.
So I installed Tkinter using this command:
python3 -m pip install tk

and the output was fine:
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting tk
  Using cached tk-0.1.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (693 bytes)
Using cached tk-0.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (3.9 kB)
Installing collected packages: tk
Successfully installed tk-0.1.0

so I tried to use the module; I wrote a basic file to display a window:
import tk
window = tk.Tk()
window.mainloop()

and then it threw me this error: AttributeError: module 'tk' has no attribute 'Tk'.
huh, weird. I checked what functions the module had, and apparently, none other than __init__, which is empty!
How do I fix this?
EDIT: info subject to change. This question is a train wreck.

What do you need to be explained?

Ah, I guess I kind of gave too much info.
I'm asking about why the init file is empty, and how to fix that.

It is quite normal for __init__.py to be empty. Do you have reasons to believe it should contain something?

tk is not tkinter, which in fact is included in the Python standard library, and thus does not need to be installed separately.

I actually tried using import tkinter, but it said that the module couldn't be found.
P.S. pardon my stupidity, but it's normal to be empty?
A while back I caught an error from inside a module, and it said that the error came from a function in init, so I assumed that's where all the magic takes place.

Lemme rewrite the question as something like "why are there no other files"

Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783810/install-tkinter-for-python (this explains why tkinter is missing on Ubuntu, and how to properly install it).

As mentioned, tkinter is in the standard library, so why look for files in site-packages?

The method __init__ is distinct from the file __init__.py which must exist, but often doesn't need to contain anything, for a directory to be a valid (non-namespace) Python package. Perhaps see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for

For some reason, it seems like it's not.
When I try to import it, it doesn't exist somehow.
May be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76105218/why-does-tkinter-or-turtle-seem-to-be-missing-or-broken-shouldnt-it-be-part.

@triplee Oh wait it's different? Ah oke.

Using apt-get to install tkinter somehow doesn't work on my machine. It says some packages couldn't be found, but apt-get update can't find them either.

Once you do get there, the source isn't that interesting.  Tkinter is actually a set of scripts written in the language tcl.  The Python code just starts up an internal tcl interpreter and creates command lines to be executed by tcl.

The package you installed is called tk and it is completely unrelated to tkinter (though the similar names are unfortunate); it is a machine learning package also called TensorKit and provides some files in a subdirectory called structure (but indeed, slightly weirdly, nothing in the tk package itself).
It is quite normal for __init__.py to be empty; this file is mandatory for a (non-namespace) Python package, but it often doesn't need to contain anything at all. See also What is __init__.py for?
In the meantime, tkinter is missing on some platforms for various reasons. To install tkinter on Ubuntu, apt-get install python3-tk.  See also Install tkinter for Python.
This question is a bit of a train wreck so it's perhaps better if you don't upvote or accept this answer, and let the question be deleted when the time comes.

For me, apt-get is broken. It can't find Tkinter. I've tried apt-get update, but that doesn't seem to work either.

You used the correct package name python3-tk? What's the output of apt-cache policy python3-tk? Probably ask a new question on [ubuntu.se] if you can't figure it out.

yup I did.
I'll probably flag this question and ask a question on Ask Ubuntu.

Alright!
I fixed it!
Just checked out this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1131280/sudo-apt-get-upgrade-results-in-404-errors-for-everything
And it fixed everything. Yay!
