# How to update a Matplotlib plot with real-time data

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am new to Matplotlib and have spent much time trying to figure out how to update my simple Matplotlib plot after the first run through my code. After i generate the plot, my code stops after the plot.show().  How do i get my code past this point to reload new data from my list? Here's a summary of my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# here i have code that generates new_data every 2 minutes

data-gathering code
new_data = [1,3,4,6,-4,2,11]

#here i display that data, but i cant get my code to get past the first display of the plot so it can generat new data and add it to the plot
    plt.plot(new_data, 'ro')
    plt.ylabel('my data results')
    plt.show()
```

Comment: See also http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/Animations

Comment: [see also](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11874767/real-time-plotting-in-while-loop-with-matplotlib/15724978#15724978)

Comment: You might also want to use `plt.pause` to make sure the gui event loop updates