# 3D Real time continuous plot using Python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I know this may be an old topic, I have searched through a lot of related topics on Google but haven't really found useful information. I am trying to get data from a microcontroller board and plot data in 3D in Python on computer. I used PySerial library to implement this and now I'm able to receive data from the port. The obstacle that I'm facing now is that I need to plot those points (consist of x,y,z) in "real time", which means once the graph is generated, it will stay on and keep updating with new points.

Initially I tried plt.show() but it didn't work well since it only shows the whole graph after the loop is done, then I tried to use plt.draw(), it seems a little bit strange while running because the GUI pop-out window always become "not responding" after a while.

I'm using Python 2.7.5 on Window.

Here is my code for plotting one point:

```
import serial
import sys
import Queue
import threading
import scipy.io
import numpy as num
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import cm


ser = serial.Serial(port='COM6',timeout=10, baudrate= 57600,bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,) 

flag = ser.isOpen() 
print flag   # check if it's opened

# draw the frame
x1 = [164, 94, 0, -100.5]
x2 = [164, 94, 0, -100.5]
y1= [-72.5, -103.5, -103.5, -134.5]
y2= [72.5, 103.5, 103.5, 134.5]
z1 = [112, 60, 3, 3]
z2 = [112, 60, 3, 3]

fig = plt.figure()
ax  = fig.add_subplot(111, projection = '3d')

ax.plot(x1, y1, z1, color = 'b')
ax.plot(x2, y2, z2, color = 'r')

plt.hold(True)



while True: 
    my_list = ser.read(9999)      # read 9999 byte
    if (ser.isOpen() == False):
        break

    n = ser.inWaiting()     # read the number of chars in the receiver buffer,
                        # after testing, I found that the max value of n is 4096
    if n == 0:
        pass

my_list = my_list.split('+00')    # split out "+00", make my_list become a list

    for item in my_list:

        # remove space
        if item == '':
            my_list.remove(item)
        else:
            item = float(item)          # convert to float type
            pass

    ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')               # to work in 3d
    x = my_list.pop(0)          # pop the first element in list to x
    Floatx= float(x)
    y = my_list.pop(0)
    Floaty= float(y)
    z = my_list.pop(0)
    Floatz= float(z)
    ax.scatter(Floatx, Floaty, Floatz)
    ax.set_xlabel('x label')
    ax.set_ylabel('y label')
    ax.set_zlabel('z label')
    plt.show()         

    ser.close()
```

Any advice and suggestion would be appreciated! Thanks! :)

Comment: what is the output of `matplotlib.get_backend( )`?

Comment: Hey I just tried on my Python, it's 'TkAgg' :) Not sure what it is though

Comment: Try calling `fig.canvas.draw()`, also see http://stackoverflow.com/a/15724978/1461210

Comment: Hey I just checked the link and I found that I need to do interactive plotting on IPython, I was wondering if this is the case, can I just move Pyserial functions into iPython and use them?