# Matplotlib animated plot as data is aquired

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, real-time

I have a script that produces real time data, is it possible to plot all of this data and show a moving curve as data is acquired using matplotlib?

Comment: I think that this has already been answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11874767/real-time-plotting-in-while-loop-with-matplotlib) and you can also read [here](http://www.instructables.com/id/Plotting-real-time-data-from-Arduino-using-Python-/) for implementation with Arduino.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matplotlib supports [animations](http://matplotlib.org/api/animation_api.html). The easiest is to look at some of the [examples](http://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/index.html).