# How to plot a graph in python using txt file with float value in it

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-widget

I need to plot in python, the graph as stress and strain

[image]

with this data

> ```
> S.No Stress Strain
> 0 0.000000 0.000000
> 1 -3343.068596 -0.520833
> 2 -3359.542402 -1.041667
> 3 -3363.690275 -1.562500
> 4 -3368.874071 -2.343750
> 5 -3375.428713 -3.515625
> 6 -3377.689516 -3.955078
> 7 -3380.871487 -4.614258
> 8 -3385.274720 -5.603027
> 9 -3386.895892 -5.973816
> 10 -3389.195531 -6.529999
> 11 -3392.487109 -7.364273
> 12 -3397.171464 -8.615685
> 13 -3398.871128 -9.084964
> 14 -3401.357499 -9.788883
> 15 -3404.965858 -10.844761
> 16 -3406.306571 -11.240716
> 17 -3408.273823 -11.834647
> 18 -3411.164927 -12.725545
> 19 -3412.242114 -13.059631
> 20 -3413.836265 -13.560761
> 21 -3416.195332 -14.312456
> 22 -3419.671825 -15.439998
> 23 -3420.967483 -15.862826
> 24 -3422.889965 -16.497069
> 25 -3425.741024 -17.448432
> 26 -3426.805424 -17.805193
> 27 -3428.391134 -18.340335
> 28 -3430.751166 -19.143049
> 29 -3434.254359 -20.347118
> 30 -3435.562196 -20.798644
> 31 -3437.512479 -21.475933
> 32 -3440.417226 -22.491867
> 33 -3441.502922 -22.872842
> 34 -3443.125125 -23.444305
> 35 -3445.546054 -24.301499
> 36 -3446.451645 -24.622947
> 37 -3447.806274 -25.105118
> 38 -3449.830488 -25.828376
> 39 -3452.850690 -26.913262
> 40 -3453.980182 -27.320094
> 41 -3455.669727 -27.930343
> 42 -3458.194084 -28.845716
> 43 -3459.138722 -29.188980
> 44 -3460.552807 -29.703877
> 45 -3462.667548 -30.476223
> 46 -3465.826112 -31.634742
> 47 -3466.981187 -32.059390
> 48 -3468.710177 -32.696362
> 49 -3470.435183 -33.333334
> ```

As an aside question, can I plot live graph while Abaqus generates the txt file?

This is the code that I'm using

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

with open("test-1-14M.txt") as f:
    data = f.read()

data = data.split('\n')

x = [row.split(' ')[0] for row in data]
y = [row.split(' ')[0] for row in data]

fig = plt.figure()

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(70)

ax1.set_title("Plot title...")    
ax1.set_xlabel('your x label..')
ax1.set_ylabel('your y label...')

ax1.plot(x, y, c='r', label='the data')

leg = ax1.legend()

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to use numpy tools, which handle low level problems :

```
from pylab import *
# load and change signs; transpose for data in lines :
data=-loadtxt('stress.txt',delimiter=' ',skiprows=1).T 
plot(data[2],data[1])
title( 'stress(strain)' )
```

gives the stress(strain) graph. Be aware that data is in lines 2 and 1.

Or even more directly with pandas :

```
from pandas import read_csv
(-read_csv('stress.txt',sep=' ')).plot('Strain','Stress')
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you've posted

> ```
> with open("test-1-14M.txt") as f:
>     data = f.read()
>
> data = data.split('\n')
>
> x = [row.split(' ')[0] for row in data]
> y = [row.split(' ')[0] for row in data]
> ```

is ***almost*** correct...

1. when you iterate on `data` you iterate also on the 1st row, that contains the heading, you want to throw away the first line using, e.g., the slice notation

   ```
   data = data.split('\n')[1:]
   ```
2. when you construct `x` and `y` you are choosing the wrong element from each line

   ```
   # see below for THE correct solution
   x = [row.split()[2] for row in data]
   y = [row.split()[1] for row in data]
   ```

   note that I used the index `2` for `x` and `1` for `y` because you want to plot stresses vs strains...
3. the lists `x`, `y` are yet not ready for plotting because they're lists of strings, you must remember to convert them to numbers (preferably when you're extracting the lists from your `data`)

   ```
   x = [float(row.split()[2]) for row in data]
   y = [float(row.split()[1]) for row in data]
   ```

There are other ways of solving your problem, maybe using `numpy` helper functions, but what you've tried is simple and with a couple of adjustments it can work OK.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out how to plot the graph,

```css
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


with open('3cube_pbc_compression_ss.txt') as f:
     data = np.loadtxt(f, delimiter=" ", dtype='float', comments="#", skiprows=0, usecols=[1,2])
 
x=data[:,1]
y=data[:,0]
fig = plt.figure()
fig.suptitle('Stress-Strain Curve of Hastyelloy C-276', fontsize=18, fontweight='bold')
plt.xlabel('Strain (%)',fontsize=14,fontweight='bold') 
plt.ylabel('Stress(MPa)',fontsize=14,fontweight='bold')
plt.plot(-x, -y, c='r', label='RT')
fig.savefig('SS-Curve.jpg', bbox_inches='tight',format='jpg', dpi=1000)
fig.savefig('SS-Curve.eps', bbox_inches='tight',format='eps', dpi=1000)
leg = plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score -1):

According to the Church-Turing thesis, everything is computable, so is this.

Note that instead of just hardcoding the values for y, you can also just parse the file.

If you're actively getting input data and want to continuously plot the data as it get's in, look into this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11874767/real-time-plotting-in-while-loop-with-matplotlib)

adapted from matplotlibs most [simple example](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_examples/pylab_examples/simple_plot.py)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

y = np.array([0, 0, 0, 1, -3343.068596, -0.520833, 2, -3359.542402, -1.041667,
              3, -3363.690275, -1.562500, 4, -3368.874071, -2.343750, 5,
              -3375.428713, -3.515625, 6, -3377.689516, -3.955078, 7,
              -3380.871487, -4.614258, 8, -3385.274720, -5.603027, 9,
              -3386.895892, -5.973816, 10, -3389.195531, -6.529999, 11,
              -3392.487109, -7.364273, 12, -3397.171464, -8.615685, 13,
              -3398.871128, -9.084964, 14, -3401.357499, -9.788883, 15,
              -3404.965858, -10.844761, 16, -3406.306571, -11.240716, 17,
              -3408.273823, -11.834647, 18, -3411.164927, -12.725545, 19,
              -3412.242114, -13.059631, 20, -3413.836265, -13.560761, 21,
              -3416.195332, -14.312456, 22, -3419.671825, -15.439998, 23,
              -3420.967483, -15.862826, 24, -3422.889965, -16.497069, 25,
              -3425.741024, -17.448432, 26, -3426.805424, -17.805193, 27,
              -3428.391134, -18.340335, 28, -3430.751166, -19.143049, 29,
              -3434.254359, -20.347118, 30, -3435.562196, -20.798644, 31,
              -3437.512479, -21.475933, 32, -3440.417226, -22.491867, 33,
              -3441.502922, -22.872842, 34, -3443.125125, -23.444305, 35,
              -3445.546054, -24.301499, 36, -3446.451645, -24.622947, 37,
              -3447.806274, -25.105118, 38, -3449.830488, -25.828376, 39,
              -3452.850690, -26.913262, 40, -3453.980182, -27.320094, 41,
              -3455.669727, -27.930343, 42, -3458.194084, -28.845716, 43,
              -3459.138722, -29.188980, 44, -3460.552807, -29.703877, 45,
              -3462.667548, -30.476223, 46, -3465.826112, -31.634742, 47,
              -3466.981187, -32.059390, 48, -3468.710177, -32.696362, 49,
              -3470.435183, -33.333334])
x = np.arange(len(y))
plt.plot(x, y)

plt.xlabel('0...n (made up as you didnt give any x data)')
plt.ylabel('your data')
plt.title('About as simple as it gets, folks')
plt.grid(True)
plt.savefig("test.png")
plt.show()
```

[image]