# real-time plotting in Torch

Tags: lua, neural-network, gnuplot, torch

I'm new to torch. I'm training a neural network model where I want to make a plot for training and validation error with each iteration, a quick search shows me plotting with gnuplot, http://torch.ch/docs/five-simple-examples.html but it's not done in real-time rather it plots the whole thing when all data from each time step/iteration is obtained.

I have made real-time plotting in python, something similar to this [real-time plotting in while loop with matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11874767/real-time-plotting-in-while-loop-with-matplotlib)

Anyway I can do it in Torch?

Answer (score 1):

You could just move the plotting code into the training loop. Then you can either rewrite the same plot on every loop or create a new plot per X iteration. Alternatively you can look at https://github.com/facebookresearch/visdom