# updated graphs through iteration, matplotlib

Tags: numpy, matplotlib

I'm trying to graph features of a data-set one by one by, via iteration.
So I want the graph to continuously update as I proceed through the loop.

I refered to this thread,[real-time plotting in while loop with matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11874767/real-time-plotting-in-while-loop-with-matplotlib) but the answers are all over the place, and despite incorporating some of their suggestions as shown below, I still can't seem to get the code working.  I'm using Jupyter Notebook.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
colors = ["darkblue", "darkgreen"]

f, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharey=True, sharex = True)


for i in range(X.shape[-1]-1):
    idx = np.where(y == 1)[0]
    ax1.scatter(X[idx, i], X[idx, i+1], color=colors[0], label=1)


    idx = np.where(y == 0)[0]
    ax2.scatter(X[idx, i], X[idx, i+1], color=colors[1], label=0)

    plt.draw()
    plt.pause(0.0001)
```

Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example for real-time plotting in a Jupyter Notebook

```
%matplotlib inline
%load_ext autoreload  #Reload all modules every time before executing the Python code typed.
%autoreload 2 
%matplotlib notebook

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import time

colors = ["darkblue", "darkgreen"]

# initialise the graph and settings

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(211)
plt.ion() # interactive mode
fig.show()
fig.canvas.draw() # matplotlib canvas drawing

# plotting loop

for i in range(X.shape[-1]-1):
  ax1.clear()
  ax2.clear()

  idx = np.where(y == 1)[0]
  ax1.scatter(X[idx, i], X[idx, i+1], color=colors[0], label=1)

  idx = np.where(y == 0)[0]
  ax2.scatter(X[idx, i], X[idx, i+1], color=colors[1], label=0)

  fig.canvas.draw() # draw
  time.sleep(0.5)   # sleep
```

Comment: Thank you, going to test it out once I have a chance.   =)

Comment: @ManelFornos Did you test that? I think this should not work and only show the final figure after the animation has finished.

Comment: It seems to be working. I'm testing it right now. I will examine it some more. Thank you.

Comment: I can't seem to figure out how to share the axes with your new code. I was tryingto  revert back to my old code with `subplots` but it was producing an error.

Answer (score 2):

For an animation you need an interactive backend. `%matplotlib inline` is no interactive backend (it essentially shows a printed version of the figure).

You may decide not to run you code in jupyter but as a script. In this case you would need to put `plt.ion()` to put interactive mode on.

Another option would be to use a `FuncAnimation`, as e.g in [this example](https://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/simple_anim.html). To run such a `FuncAnimation` in Jupyter you will still need some interactive backend, either `%matplotlib tk` or `%matplotlib notebook`.

From matplotlib 2.1 on, we can also create an animation using JavaScript.

```
from IPython.display import HTML
HTML(ani.to_jshtml())
```

Some complete example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation
import numpy as np

t = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi)
x = np.sin(t)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.axis([0,2*np.pi,-1,1])
l, = ax.plot([],[])

def animate(i):
    l.set_data(t[:i], x[:i])

ani = matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=len(t))

from IPython.display import HTML
HTML(ani.to_jshtml())
```