# I have a dictionary of 8 figures that I would like to better visualize by cycling through as an animation

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a dictionary titled "fig_dict" and a corresponding dictionary titled "axes_dict". Currently, if I want to plot a particular figure I can just call fig_dict['key_of_interest'].show(). I also have a list of the dictionary keys (both are the same) titled dict_keys.

I would like to cycle through all keys and plot them like this: https://www.timera-energy.com/content/uploads/2014/11/Fwd-Curve-Animation.gif , where each figure is flashed for a certain amount of time and the cycle is repeated.

In my head this looks like:

```
for current_key in dict_keys:
    fig_dict[current_key].animate()
```

All other stackoverflow questions I can find on this topic don't deal with pre-made figures and don't seem to work. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Could you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that generates a toy set of figures and your dictionaries for ppl to play with?

Answer (score 0):

This is not going to work as each figure is a separate window and could be located in different places on the screen. It's much better to have a single figure and redraw the axis each animation loop (e.g. use interactive mode with `plt.ion()`, pause to redraw `plt.pause(0.1)` and clear the axis with `ax.cla()` like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11874767/real-time-plotting-in-while-loop-with-matplotlib?noredirect=1&lq=1)).

If you need to use your current format, I'd suggest creating a series of images and then making a video/gif from these files, e.g.

```
for i, current_key in enumerate(dict_keys):
    fig_dict[current_key].savefig("out{:05}.png".format(i))
```

and then make a video or gif (e.g. ffmpeg, gifsicle, etc),

```
ffmpeg -i out_%05d.png test.avi
```

some care may be in needed as the order of dictionaries are undefined.