# Plot a rolling window with Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot a time series in a `while` loop as a rolling window: The graph should always show the 10 most recent observations.

My idea was to use a [deque object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque) with `maxlen=10` and plot it in every step.
To my great surprise the plot *appends* new values to the old plot; apparently it remembers values that are no longer inside the deque! Why is that and how can I switch it off?

[image]

This is a minimal example of what I am trying to do. The plotting part is based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15720891/4743630) (although `plt.ion()` did not change anything for me, so I left it out):

```
from collections import deque
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = 0
data = deque(maxlen=10)

while True:
    x += np.abs(np.random.randn())
    y = np.random.randn()
    data.append((x, y))

    plt.plot(*zip(*data), c='black')
    plt.pause(0.1)
```

I also tried to use Matplotlib's animation functions instead, but could not figure out how to do that in an infinite `while` loop...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nowadays, it's much easier (and offers much better performance) to use [the `animation` module](https://matplotlib.org/api/animation_api.html) than to use multiple calls to `plt.plot`:

```
from collections import deque
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import numpy as np

def animate(i):
    global x
    x += np.abs(np.random.randn())
    y = np.random.randn()
    data.append((x, y))
    ax.relim()
    ax.autoscale_view()
    line.set_data(*zip(*data))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x = 0
y = np.random.randn()
data = deque([(x, y)], maxlen=10)
line, = plt.plot(*zip(*data), c='black')

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=100)
plt.show()
```