# plot mouse movement Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, pynput

I would like to plot the movement of the mouse in near real-time using matplotlib and pynput, but I suspect I am getting some issues with the code being blocked. Code is uses a simplified version of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15724978/5422525).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pynput import mouse
from time import sleep

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.set_xlim(0, 1920-1)
ax.set_ylim(0, 1080-1)
plt.show(False)
plt.draw()

x,y = [0,0]
points = ax.plot(x, y, 'o')[0]
# cache the background
background = fig.canvas.copy_from_bbox(ax.bbox)

def on_move(x, y):
    points.set_data(x,y)
    # restore background
    fig.canvas.restore_region(background)
    # redraw just the points
    ax.draw_artist(points)
    # fill in the axes rectangle
    fig.canvas.blit(ax.bbox)

with mouse.Listener(on_move=on_move) as listener:
    sleep(10)
```

The code seems to halt on `ax.draw_artist(points)`. The pynput mouse listener is a `threading.Thread`, and all callbacks are invoked from the thread. I am not familiar enough with the inner workings of matplotlib or threading to determine what is the cause.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It might cause problems to run a thread with GUI input in parallel with the matplotlib GUI.
In any case, it could make more sense to use matplotlib tools only. There is an [event handling mechanism](https://matplotlib.org/users/event_handling.html) available, which provides a `"motion_notify_event"` to be used to obtain the current mouse position. A callback registered for this event would then store the mouse position and blit the updated points.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.set_xlim(0, 1920-1)
ax.set_ylim(0, 1080-1)

x,y = [0], [0]
# create empty plot
points, = ax.plot([], [], 'o')

# cache the background
background = fig.canvas.copy_from_bbox(ax.bbox)

def on_move(event):
    # append event's data to lists
    x.append(event.xdata)
    y.append(event.ydata)
    # update plot's data  
    points.set_data(x,y)
    # restore background
    fig.canvas.restore_region(background)
    # redraw just the points
    ax.draw_artist(points)
    # fill in the axes rectangle
    fig.canvas.blit(ax.bbox)


fig.canvas.mpl_connect("motion_notify_event", on_move)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Interesting, I wasn't aware of this possibility. For anyone interested in closing the figure after a set time, or running some code in between drawing, `plt.show(block=False)` and `plt.pause(sec)` can be combined with this.