# How to make live graphs plotted in a single one graph?

Tags: python, plot

I'm trying to show real-time graphs(dynamic plotting) using python. However, the result didn't show in a single one graph, but generate a new one each second, which didn't mean updating live graph. How can I solve it? Is there any problem in my code?

```
import serial
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from drawnow import drawnow

DataList = []
pcs = serial.Serial('COM4', baudrate = 9600, timeout = 1)
time.sleep(3)
plt.ion()

def makeFig():
    plt.plot(DataList, 'rd-')

def getValues():
    pcs.write(b"MEASure:VOLTage:DC?\n")
    pcsData = pcs.readline().decode('ascii').split('\n\r')
    DataList.append(float(pcsData[0]))


while(1):
    getValues()
    drawnow(makeFig)
    plt.pause(.000001)
```

---

The result snapshot:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `drawnow` called in this way is designed as  one-shot draw. See if `drawnow(caller, show_once=True)` corrects your problem, else you may need to look elsewhere - such as using alternative plotting functions:

[How do I plot in real-time in a while loop using matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11874767/how-do-i-plot-in-real-time-in-a-while-loop-using-matplotlib)