# Fastest Way to Update and Plot Lists?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, matplotlib

I am relatively new at programming, so I apologize in advance if anything is unclear:

The program that I am working on finds the position of certain facial landmarks in a webcam and plots lists of position values in matplotlib's PyPlot. The program struggles to track seven different landmarks at once, running at ~2 frames per second when trying to do so.

Here is the basic idea:

```
fig1 = plt.figure("Facial Landmark Positions")
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(2,4,1)
a_list = []
while True:
  ab,cd,... = datavalues    #Data comes in a list of ordered pairs
  a,b = ab
  a_list.append(a)
  ax1.clear()
  ax1.plot(timevalues,a_list)
  plt.pause(0.01)
  plt.show(block=False)
```

Most likely, I will just reduce the number of landmarks the program is tracking, but I am just curious: Is there a faster way to update lists?

Comment: Where does the number seven come into play here?

Comment: Related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11874767/how-do-i-plot-in-real-time-in-a-while-loop-using-matplotlib).

Comment: I closed as duplicate of what is *the fastest* (not the easiest) way to update plots in matplotlib.