# Matplotlib draw Figures during ginput()

Tags: python, matplotlib, select, coordinates, ginput

I am using ginput on an image. I would like to extend the ginput function a little, such that when I click somewhere, it will immediately draw a box with specific dimensions around the selected point. Is there a way to update the image every time after I clicked somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, [and found the solution in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11874767/how-do-i-plot-in-real-time-in-a-while-loop-using-matplotlib) - you can force an update using the pause command after you have plotted your box, this forces an update:

```
plt.pause(0.05)
```