# How do I update/redraw existing matplotlib figure with updated dataFrame

Tags: python, matplotlib, real-time, line-plot

I have built a GUI in Qt Creator that accepts some user input, performs some calculations, then updates some labels.  Callbacks are used to update these labels as the user changes the various input text fields. If the user selects a checkbox, a simple plot is generated using the data calculated during a callback.

My problem is a new figure is generated each time the code runs via a callback. Ideally, the figure window would be static and I would just see my lineplot react to the user inputs as they are changed.

I have spent days trying everything my Google searches would return and none seem to work. I have tried:

[How to update a plot in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098131/how-to-update-a-plot-in-matplotlib)

[How do I plot in real-time in a while loop using matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11874767/how-do-i-plot-in-real-time-in-a-while-loop-using-matplotlib)

and too many combinations of plt.ion(), plt.ioff(), plt.draw() etc. to no avail.

```
# --- START PLOT
        sns.set_theme(context="paper", style="darkgrid")
        sns.set_color_codes(palette='muted')

        fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(
            figsize=(
                10,
                6.18))  # plt.subplots is a function that returns a tuple containing a figure and axes object(s)

        # PC Plot creation
        # Create first y-axis (Efficiency)
        ax1.set_title('Project:  ' + project + '\n' + 'Turbine Performance Curve\n'
                      + 'D = ' + str(d) + 'm ' + 'RPM = ' + str(n) + ' ' + turb_description + '\n')
        ax1.set_xlabel('Flow (cms)', labelpad=5)
        ax1.set_ylabel('Efficiency (%)', labelpad=5)
        ax1 = sns.lineplot(x="Flow (cms)", y="Efficiency (%)", data=df1, color="steelblue", label='Efficiency',
                           legend=None, linewidth=2)

        # Create second y-axis (Power) and plot line
        ax2 = ax1.twinx()
        ax2.set_ylabel('Power (kW)', labelpad=15)
        ax2 = sns.lineplot(x="Flow (cms)", y="Power (kW)", data=df1, color="indianred", label='Output',
                           legend=None,
                           linewidth=2)

        # Add QDesign line
        sns.lineplot(x="Flow (cms)", y="Output (kW)", data=df3, color="grey", linewidth=2,
                     label='Qdesign' + ' = ' + str(q) + 'cms', legend=None)

        # Format grid lines
        ax2.grid(b=True, which='major', color='lightslategrey', linewidth=0.25)
        ax2.grid(b=True, which='minor', color='lightslategrey', linewidth=0.05)
        ax1.grid(b=True, which='major', color='lightslategrey', linewidth=0.25)
        ax1.grid(b=True, which='minor', color='lightslategrey', linewidth=0.05)

        # Set Axis limits
        ax1.set_xlim(q11minplot * h ** 0.5 * d * d * 0.5, qmaxplot)
        ax1.set_ylim(0, 100)
        ax2.set_ylim(bottom=0)

        # Add Legend
        fig.legend(loc=1, bbox_to_anchor=(0.94, 0.992))

        # Set second y axis grid same as first
        ax2.set_yticks(np.linspace(ax2.get_yticks()[0], ax2.get_yticks()[-1], len(ax1.get_yticks())))
        plt.minorticks_on()
        return plt
```

Is there a way, when I roll through this code again from a callback with an updated `df1` dataframe, to just update the existing figure window instead of generating a new one.

Comment: you're gonna want to use raw matplotlib for that. `ax.plot` returns the line artists, and you can update their x- and -y data dynamically

Comment: Thanks Paul, are you able to elaborate a bit or perhaps provide a link on what you mean by 'raw' matplotlib?

Comment: I mean using matplotlib functions and object methods instead of seaborn

Comment: @PaulH can you provide an example as an answer.  I am also having challenges implementing this.  My bars do not get updated properly.

Comment: Have you checked the MPL website? Looks of object-oriented examples there