# How to update a matplotlib chart displayed in a window?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am attempting to write a sample chart that updates on every 0.5 seconds.

The code is like so:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import time

# Some example data to display
x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 400)
y = np.sin(x ** 2)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2)

i = 5
for row in x:
    axs[0, 0].plot(x[len(x) - i:], y[len(y) - i:])
    axs[0, 0].set_title("main")

    axs[1, 0].plot(x, y ** 2)
    axs[1, 0].set_title(f"shares {i} with main")
    axs[1, 0].sharex(axs[0, 0])

    axs[0, 1].plot(x + 1, y + 1)
    axs[0, 1].set_title("unrelated")

    axs[1, 1].plot(x + 2, y + 2)
    axs[1, 1].set_title("also unrelated")

    fig.canvas.draw()
    fig.canvas.flush_events()
    fig.tight_layout()
    i += 1
    plt.show()

    print('THIS NEVER PRINTS - IT SEEMS TO BLOCK ON THE show() CALL ABOVE')
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

If you run it, the charts will be displayed. But that `show()` call seems to block, and the loop never executes to update the charts.

How can I make it update?

Comment: Are you wanting to have the figure appear and then dynamically update the content over time? [Interactive mode for matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/users/interactive.html) might help out, or perhaps using the `plt.pause` function [as per this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11874767/how-do-i-plot-in-real-time-in-a-while-loop-using-matplotlib)

Comment: That was it! If you post as an answer I can accept - thanks!