# Calling plotting function from loop in main function hangs at plot

Tags: python, loops, matplotlib, plot, user-input

I have written a function `masterplot()` which applies some logic to input data, sets up plot parameters, and plots the data using matplotlib.pyplot's interactive plotting feature. The input data is from an input function which I'll call `getInput()`. This is user-facing code that I am trying to future-proof, idiot-proof, and streamline, so it uses Python's `input()` function somewhat extensively. The main loop will run the plot function once, then ask the user if they wish to run the code again on a new set of input data.

The problem occurs when running the code, the interactive plot will appear but hangs. The code still functions properly, asking for user input and repeating if necessary, but until the main loop ends the plots are left hanging (blank, non-interactable, circular loading cursor when moused over, etc.). As soon as the code finishes executing, either via user interrupt (ctrl+c) or the user telling the code to end via the prompt, all graphs become active again and the data shows as expected. Is there a way to do make the graph show properly while looping through the code?

A simplified version of my code is as follows:

Note 1: This function reads input data from a folder containing numbered csv files I'm extracting a column of data from and returns 2 arrays. The specific folder is chosen by the user from a list of possible options. **I don't believe this is the issue, but am including it just in case.**

Note 2: This function calls the previous to get the x- and y- arrays, configures some figure options, and finds the 5-point rolling average of the data.

Note 3: The main function is the one executed, running the main plot function once before asking the user if they wish to rerun it (to analyze a different input).

```py
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator as ML

def getInput(): # Note 1
    x, y = [], []
    os.chdir(input("Select folder: "))
    files = os.listdir()
    for file in files:
        data = pd.read_csv(file, usecols=[coi])
        Xmax = np.max(np.asarray(data))
        x.append(Xmax)
        y.append(int(file))
    return(np.asarray(x) ,np.assaray(y))

def masterplot(): # Note 2
    x, y = getI()
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(ML(4))
    ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(ML(20))
    ax.grid(True)
    ax.scatter(x, y, s=5, color = 'Gray')
    ax.set_xlim(0, 1.05 * max(x))
    w = 5
    Isum = np.cumsum(x) 
    ravg = (Isum[w:] - Isum[:-w]) / w
    while len(ravg) != len(t): ravg = np.insert(ravg, 0, x[0])
    ax.plot(x, ravg, lw=15, alpha = 0.1, c='k', label="%s point rolling average" %w)
    ax.legend(loc = 1)
    plt.show()

def main(i=1): # Note 3
    while True:
        i += 1
        masterplot()
        if i > 1:
            cont = input("Examine additional data? [Y/N]: ").capitalize()
            if cont != 'Y' and cont !='N': print("Invalid input"); continue
            elif cont == 'N': break
            else: continue
        else: continue

main()
```

I've tried about every variation of pyplot options, including the block argument in `plt.show()`, as well as re-writing the code in a variety of ways.

The expected outcome is the code executes and a figure appears which the user can view and interact with, and choose to run the code again without needing to first close the figure.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Have you tried `plt.ion()` and/or `plt.pause(0.01)`? `ion` is for interactive plotting and `pause` will often force the figure to show without blocking. Also, I edited your post and put the imports on their own lines which is typically how it is done in Python.

Comment: @jared **This fixed my issue**, thank you. I somehow missed plt.pause() in my search of pyplot documentation.  As an aside, I was simply experimenting with condensing my code with the import line(to any readers detriment, of course :P)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I plot in real-time in a while loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11874767/how-do-i-plot-in-real-time-in-a-while-loop)