# matplotlib window freezing / hanging on close in ipython with OS X

Tags: matplotlib, plot, ipython, freeze

This problem has affected everyone I work with that updated to the *currently latest* versions below. This only affects `ipython` plots. The regular `python` terminal is unaffected by this issue.

### Reproduction

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot()
# manually close the window with `x`
```

Attempting `plt.close()` also disables the three native `OS X` window buttons

### Workaround

Us the shortcut for closing `ipython` and then cancel the exit

```
^+d
Do you really want to exit ([y]/n)? n
```

### Versions

```
ipython 5.0.0
matplotlib 1.5.1 
OS X El Capitan Version 10.11.6
```

### Related

- https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/9659
- [Cannot manually close matplotlib plot window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34108696/cannot-manually-close-matplotlib-plot-window)
- https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/5624/

Comment: Issue opened: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/6908