# %matplotlib inline versus %matplotlib notebook display problems in pythonAnywhere jupyter

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter, pythonanywhere

This is not a duplicate as suggested.   I am not trying to switch backends. I am just trying to use the `%matplotlib notebook` formulation.    Moreover, the solutions suggested in that other question (*place the`%matplotlib notebook` before the the `from matplotlib import pylplot as plt`  OR trying call the magic command twice in a  row*) do not work for me. The behavior (blank notebook charts) remains.

---

place the`%matplotlib notebook` before the the `from matplotlib import pylplot as plt`  OR trying call the magic command twice in a  row

When I use `%matplotlib inline`  my charts always show,  but they're generally on the small side, and have no ability to zoom/pan.

When I use `%matplotlib notebook` I get zoomable, pannable charts,  but I sometimes encounter problems where the charts display as blank.

[image]

Background:

PythonAnywhere notebook 3.6 Python.  Using update Google Chrome from Windows 7.

If I reopen my existing notebook,  even restart the kernel and re-run all the cells,  all my `.plot()` appear blank.  But if I contemporaneously start a brand new 3.6 notebook,  `%matplotlib notebook` plots work fine.  Killing all the jupyter-related processes doesn't help either.

This does not always occur.  But if one chart appears blank, they all appear blank.

I would like to use the `notebook` magic,  but this problem is pretty profound.

[image]

Comment: This sometimes occurs due to wrong order of commands You can refer to this question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43545050/using-matplotlib-notebook-after-matplotlib-inline-in-jupyter-notebook-doesnt

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using %matplotlib notebook after %matplotlib inline in Jupyter Notebook doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43545050/using-matplotlib-notebook-after-matplotlib-inline-in-jupyter-notebook-doesnt)

Comment: @VrushM  Yeah thanks for that pointer. I tried all those variations, but still getting the same behavior.

Comment: It's hard to say what's happening if this only occurs sometimes. What would be needed is a [mcve] of the issue. I guess that would require you to do more testing with reproducible data leading to a clear problem description, like "if I perform <step1>, <step2>, I get a blank plot, but if I perform <step1>, <step3>, the plot is shown correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I have found some stability on using `%matplotlib` notebook, after including `plt.close()`, before all my plots.

A pretty dirty solution, I know, but it's working. Here Windows 10, Python 3.6.2 and Jupyter 6.03 (updated Jupyter haven't solved the issue).
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

`%matplotlib qt` will do your job.