# Plotting a 3D scatter plot using Python only returns an empty space (Jupyter Notebook)

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I am trying to create a 3D scatter plot using matplotlib in a Jupyter Notebook page. The code is not returning any errors, but I have yet to have the plot actually show up. The output is just blank.

Python: 3.7.3
Matplotlib: 3.0.3

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

%matplotlib inline
%matplotlib notebook

threedee = plt.figure().gca(projection='3d')
threedee.scatter(existing_df_2d.PC1, existing_df_2d.PC2, 
existing_df_2d.data_mean)

plt.show()
```

I included an example of the output (it's blank):

[image: Output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using two backends

```
%matplotlib inline 
%matplotlib notebook
```

As a result, there seems to be a conflict between the two backends when invoked in parallel one after the other.

P.S: When I tried putting `%matplotlib notebook` in the same cell as the rest of the code, I did not see any figure. When I put it in a different cell, I see the figure.

**Solution**: Just use either the `%matplotlib inline` or `%matplotlib notebook` in a new separate cell and things will work fine

Comment: It worked! Thank you! Just out of curiosity, what is the difference between them? When should one be used over the other?

Comment: @alkhalifas : `%matplotlib notebook` allows you interactive functionalities such as rotating 3d figure, zooming in figures, within the notebook. By the way, I just realised that there is similar question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43545050/using-matplotlib-notebook-after-matplotlib-inline-in-jupyter-notebook-doesnt)

Answer (score -1):

In my experience, `%matplotlib notebook` doesn't work with 3D plots unfortunately. Just use `%matplotlib inline` and you should be OK.