# Matplotlib FuncAnimation not plotting any chart inside Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Simple matplotlib plot. Here is my code

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
from itertools import count
import random

x = []
y = []
index=count()
def animate(i):
    x.append(next(index))
    y.append(random.randint(0,10))
    plt.plot(x,y)

a = FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(),animate,interval=1000)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Running the code above I get

```
<Figure size 576x396 with 0 Axes>
```

but no chart appears.

Comment: If the suggested answer solved your problem, would you mind selecting it as the answer for your question?   thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Jupyter notebooks to run it? I tried with native libraries and it works just fine. The plots are visible.

Checking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43545050/using-matplotlib-notebook-after-matplotlib-inline-in-jupyter-notebook-doesntv) i see the same situation. Could you try to use `%matplotlib inline` before importing matplotlib as:

```
%matplotlib inline # this line before importing matplotlib
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
```

That said, the animation can be displayed using JavaScript. This is similar to the ani.to_html5() solution, except that it does not require any video codecs.

```
from IPython.display import HTML
HTML(a.to_jshtml())
```

this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35532498/animation-in-ipython-notebook/46878531#46878531) brings a more complete overview...

Comment: Yes, I am using jupyter notebook. Even after using %matplotlib inline , I am getting an empty graph

Comment: I think the issue is with the animation. as described [here](http://louistiao.me/posts/notebooks/embedding-matplotlib-animations-in-jupyter-as-interactive-javascript-widgets/) you would need to use HTML5 video to render the animation...