# Using %matplotlib notebook or %matplotlib notebook does not work when run py file in colab

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython, google-colaboratory

I have a file named `utils.py`. In that file I have a function named `plot_results` defined as below:

```
def plot_results(results, epochs):
    """
    The function to show results on each epoch.

    Parameters:
        results (keras.history): History of each epoch. It comes directly from keras.
        epochs (int): The number of epochs.
    """
    _, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)

    ax1.set_xlabel("Epochs")
    ax1.set_ylabel("Losses")
    ax1.plot(
        range(1, epochs+1),
        results.history['val_loss'],
        label="Validation loss",
        marker='o')
    ax1.plot(
        range(1, epochs+1),
        results.history['loss'],
        label="loss",
        marker='o')
    ax1.legend()

    ax2.set_xlabel("Epochs")
    ax2.set_ylabel("Accuracies")
    ax2.plot(
        range(1, epochs+1),
        [accuracy * 100 for accuracy in results.history['accuracy']],
        label="Accuracy",
        marker='o')
    ax2.plot(
        range(1, epochs+1),
        [accuracy * 100 for accuracy in results.history['val_accuracy']],
        label="validation accuracy",
        marker='o')
    ax2.legend()

    plt.show()
```

I also have a file named `main.py` which in that file I call `plot_results`. When I run `main.py` in local machine I get correctly the plot visualized.

But when I run it in a google colab cell as:

```
! python main.py --ne 1
```

I just get `<Figure size 640x480 with 2 Axes>`
according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43545050/using-matplotlib-notebook-after-matplotlib-inline-in-jupyter-notebook-doesnt) I tried:

```
%matplotlib inline
! python main.py --ne 1
```

And:

```
%matplotlib notebook
! python main.py --ne 1
```

And:

```
%matplotlib inline
%matplotlib notebook
! python main.py --ne 1
```

But none of them work.
How can I show the plot in that function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
%run main.py
```

It will work like running line by line.