# Anaconda on Mac: Can't set Matplotlib backend to Agg

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, backend, spyder

I want to set Spyder to use a non-interactive matplotlib backend, so that plot figures do not pop up but I can still save figures to file, [like this hint](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34583288/2453202).

However, it looks like Spyder automatically imports matplotlib and sets the backend internally somewhere, so any call I make to `matplotlib.use()` pops an error saying that MPL has already been called.

Prefs show that "automatically import PyLab" is disabled.  Also there is no 'Agg' backend in the dropdown list.

How do I use a non-interactive backend?

Or preferably: how can I allow command-line setting of the backend again?  (I would like my script to choose whether to use the interactive/non-interactive backends depending on some variables, before MPL import.)

Spyder prefs Screenshot:
[image]

Versions/attempt, on Mac OS 10.13.6 (shows MPL already imported!):

```
Python 3.6.6 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Jun 28 2018, 11:07:29)

IPython 6.5.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.

>> matplotlib
Using matplotlib backend: Qt5Agg
```

Comment: I think the option you are looking for is to turn support off, i.e. deactivate "Activate support". Then Spyder will just execute whatever you type in your script.

Comment: Another question with solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44086597/cant-use-matplotlib-useagg-graphs-always-show-on-the-screen?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) As mentioned by [@ImportanceOfBeingErnest](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4124317/importanceofbeingernest) in his comment above, you simply need to turn off the option called *Activate Support* in the screenshot you posted to be able to set by yourself the Matplotlib backend you want to use in your code.