# Why importing matplotlib.pyplot changes backend?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, ssh

I need to use `TkAgg` *backend* in `matplotlib` to plot on my machine (A) while calculating via *ssh* in another machine (B).

Following other questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3285193/how-to-switch-backends-in-matplotlib-python), I do:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
matplotlib.get_backend() # prints: 'TkAgg'

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
matplotlib.get_backend() # prints: 'agg'

# Plotting...
import numpy as np
t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
s = 1 + np.sin(2 * np.pi * t)

plt.plot(t, s)
plt.show()
```

But gives the error:

```
UserWarning: Matplotlib is currently using agg, which is a non-GUI backend, so cannot show the figure.
```

It seems that every time I import `matplotlib.pyplot` it switches back to the default backend!

What do I need to do?

Comment: Are you running this code on the server or on your machine? If the server has no DISPLAY how should it show the figure?

Comment: I am using `ssh -X` that should open a window in my mac using Xquartz

Comment: Are you using matplotlib 3.0? Did it work previously with matplotlib 2.2.x?

Comment: Also, did you try `plt.switch_backend` and also `matplotlib.use(... , force=True)`?

Comment: never tried before on this machine with matplotlib 2.2

Comment: How did you solve it? Any progress.

Comment: @PrameshBajracharya I didn't...