# Corrupted visual from python chromeos linux

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, pygame, chromebook

I am using a chromebook with linux beta turned on to use a terminal to run python3 scripts. they worked fine until recently when any pop out window (pygame, pyplot) look corrupted. the windows have black bars covering them for pyplot or are completely covered in black for pygame. the code in the python scripts are unchanged and worked just fine a couple of weeks ago.

I have already turned off linux beta, then returned it back on, reinstalling packages which didn't alleviate the issue. Any help is IMMENSELY appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

I installed Qt5 bindings via `pip install PyQt5` and changed the backend to `Qt5Agg` per [How to change backends in matplotlib / Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3285193/how-to-change-backends-in-matplotlib-python) and that fixed the black bars for me.