# Change matplotlib default backend at system level

Tags: python, matplotlib

I know I can change the default matplotlib backend when importing matplotlib in my code like [the answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3285193/how-to-change-backends-in-matplotlib-python). But I'm sure there's a way to change the default backend configuration at system level, by uncommenting a line in a file.

The problem is: I don't remember what file it is and I wasn't able to find it at the documentation. This is important because I don't want to use agg as the default, as it's not a GUI backend.

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html#the-matplotlibrc-file

Comment: yeap, that's the page I was looking for... thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found it... it's the **matplotlibrc** file. In a virtual environment it is located at `venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data/matplotlibrc`