# DataFrame (pandas) plot opens window but there is no plot

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, plot

I am unable to produce any charts in Python (matplotlib 3.5.1) with the pandas DataFrame plot() method. A window opens and the axes return value is <AxesSubplot:> as opposed to returning an object like that prints as somethig like <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x7f3958bcf9d0>, which is what I usually see when the plot works.

The backend is QtAgg and as far as I can tell from a poke between fora pages that report a similar problem this should be all right. This is also not a problem with needing to run matplotlib.pyplot.ion() as I see a window open, but it is black with no plot in it.

Any advice would be useful, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the (mis)behaviour without really being sure that I have resolved the issue responsible for this misbehaviour.

As looked around for a way out, I found this discussion ([How to change backends in matplotlib / Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3285193/how-to-change-backends-in-matplotlib-python)) which made a lot of getting the back end setting right. Wondering if that would make a difference, I changed the back end. The QtAgg back end loaded by default from the matplotlibrc file and so following the instructions in the post on how to permanently change the back end, I modified the file so that the back end is now Qt5Agg. The data now plots.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hello Community, I hope the answer is clearer now.