# What is the fastest backend to plot big dataset with matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am actually facing the problem of matplotlib being slow, expecially because I am dealing with huge datasets to plot. Is it possible to switch through matplotlib backends to plot faster and what is the best solution to plot big datas? Does anybody advice to use non-builtin backends? Thanks

Comment: Mathplotlib is generally not very fast indeed, but this is often sufficient to plot reasonably large dataset. If you want to plot really large data then doing that is actually the problem: you need to reduce you data first. If a trivial reduction is not possible, then you eyes and your brain are not gonna be able to compute the plotted data if it is too huge anyway ;) . The resulting plot will certainly be awful too. Thus, the question is what do you want *exactly* to plot with it?

Comment: By the way, for the backend, please read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3285193/how-to-change-backends-in-matplotlib-python